# Flashcard Package Isn't Compiling in Latex

Tags: packages, flashcards

I start by saying that I have zero aptitude for coding and programming.

I'm using MikTeX, the most recent version I believe, and WinEdt as my interface. I want to use the flashcard package so I can generate some flashcards that I'll be able to print out. The Anki flashcard software doesn't do it for me (in case anyone is to suggest this).

Anyway, I've installed the flashcard package; it was in my Package Manager. However, I can't get it to compile the pdf that I need. Here's an example of the code that I tried to compile that was taken directly from the documentation:

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}


\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Norm on a Linear Space \\ Normed Space}

A real-valued function $||x||$ defined on a linear space $X$, where
$x \in X$, is said to be a \emph{norm on} $X$ if


\smallskip

\begin{description}
\item [Positivity] $||x|| \geq 0$,
\item [Triangle Inequality] $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$,
\item [Homogeneity] $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \: ||x||$,
$\alpha$ an arbitrary scalar,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x=0$,
\end{description}

\smallskip

where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points in $X$.

\medskip

A linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed space}.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}

Let $X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:

\medskip

\begin{description}
\item [Additivity] $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity] $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry] $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}


\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Linear Transformation/Operator}

A transformation $L$ of (operator on) a linear space $X$ into a linear
space $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have the same scalar field, is said to be
a \emph{linear transformation (operator)} if

\medskip

\begin{enumerate}
\item $L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x), \forall x\in X$ and $\forall$
scalars $\alpha$, and
\item $L(x_1 + x_2) = L(x_1) + L(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

This is the error that it generated:

```
Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-    option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Latex\testing4.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Latex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Latex/testing4.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.

("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\flashcards\flashcard
s.cls"
Document Class: flashcards 2010/08/13 1.0.1 (matthew@debian.org)
("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
Coudln't find avery5388.cfg, using defualt.
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...@onefilewithoptions #1[{\cardpaper 
                                              }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
l.77 \setlength
           {\oddevenshift}{\oddoffset}
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

I've tried some other very simple examples as well, and nothing happens. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried a simpler example shown below:

```
\documentclass[avery5371]{flashcards}
\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{Start}
To finish
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

And it generated this error:

```
Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-    option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Latex\Testing 2.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Latex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Latex/Testing 2.tex"
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.

("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\flashcards\flashcard
s.cls"
Document Class: flashcards 2010/08/13 1.0.1 (matthew@debian.org)
("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
Coudln't find avery5371.cfg, using defualt.
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ...@onefilewithoptions #1[{\cardpaper 
                                              }][{}]\noexpand \@pkgexten...
l.77 \setlength
           {\oddevenshift}{\oddoffset}
?
```

I think I didn't install the package properly. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When I try compiling this it works perfectly for me, which adds credence to your guess that your install isn't working properly.

I'm not totally sure where the install broke, but you might be successful if you save this file as `avery5371.cfg` in the same folder as your .tex file:

```
%%
%% This is file `avery5371.cfg',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% flashcards.dtx  (with options: `avery5371')
%% 
%% FlashCards LaTeX2e Class for Typesetting Double Sided Cards
%% Copyright (C) 2000  Alexander M. Budge <ambudge@mit.edu>
%% 
%% This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
%% it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
%% the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
%% (at your option) any later version.
%% 
%% This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
%% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
%% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
%% GNU General Public License for more details.
%% 
%% You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
%% along with this program (the file COPYING); if not, write to the
%% Free Software Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA.
%% 
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{avery5371.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{5}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2}
\setlength{\cardheight}{2.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{0.50in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.75in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.75in}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `avery5371.cfg'.
```

Alternately, try removing [avery5371.cfg] from your document class options, and see if it can find the package at all.

Comment: Thanks, here's a really dumb question...how exactly do I find my .tex file? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Also, you were correct. I took out the portion you told me to, and I "uninstalled" just in case. This is the error I got when I tried to reinstall again by compiling:
Unfortunately, the package flashcards could not be installed.
! LaTeX Error: File `flashcards.cls' not found.
How do I get the flashcards.cls and what folder do I put it in exactly?

Comment: The trick worked. +1